# Batch Script To Combine Multiple Files With Same String (but a wildcard!) Into A Zip

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

I’m looking for a way of using 7Z to zip several files with the same into a .7z/.zip file.

Within my directory I have hundreds of files with differing amounts of ‘tracks’ like so;

```
Zebrafile.cue
Zebrafile (Track 1).bin
Zebrafile (Track 2).bin

Donkeyfile.cue
Donkeyfile (Track 1).bin
Donkeyfile (Track 2).bin
Donkeyfile (Track 3).bin

Extradonkeyfile.cue
Extradonkeyfile (Track 1).bin
```

And I need a way of zipping these files together automatically so I just end up with

```
Zebrafile.zip
Donkeyfile.zip
Extradonkeyfile.zip
```

I guess the script would have to match the whole filename from the start UP TO the space before the opening bracket "(" somehow! The only variable after that match would be the number of the track "(Track X)"

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction? I have seen other batch files which get close, but I'm still unsure of how to get the batch file to take into account the changing Track #. Many thanks!

Comment: Couldn't the presence of `filename.CUE` be used to cue a compression operation?

Comment: At cmd line: `@for %A in (*.cue) do @7z a "%~nA.zip" "%~nA*.*"`

Comment: `@for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b/a-d *.cue^|sort /r') do @7z a "%~nA.zip" "%%A"` "%~nA*.bin" to guard against `cat.cue` + `catfish.cue`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work. If it is in a .bat script, double the '%' on the 'f' variable. This will put the .cue and .bin files into one archive file. If you want a .zip format file, use `-tzip`.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %f IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "*.cue"') DO (7z a -tzip "%~nf.zip" "%~f" "%~nf (*.bin")
```

Comment: Um, no. Suppose we have `cat.cue` and `cat fish.cue`. `cat.cue` will be processed first and would include `cat fish (track 1).bin`. Including the `sort` would ensure that `cat fish` is processed before `cat`.

Comment: @Magoo - Sorting will change the order, but the "cat fish" files would still be processed with "cat." I have added a ( that should eleminate that possibility.

Comment: Depends on whether the `sdel` option is invoked. `pkzip`'s `m` option deletes the source after compression, but `7zip` you need `-sdel` - and if that was invoked, then the `cat fish` files would no longer exist when `cat` was compressed. As always, there are many possibilities.